# ionic 2 storage not working with variables

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am not sure what the problem is here but i can't return a value. I do not want to use sqlite right now.

```
 doLogin(event){
    this.storage.get('user').then((val) => {
      this.username=val;
      console.log(this.username);
      console.log(val);
  });

}
```

The problem is the 1st log returns undefined but the second log is returning the correct values.

Edit : 
Really **sorry** guys. Both the logs are working fine. But the log mentioned below is not working. This is causing the if statement to return false even though all the values match
Full code for the file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

   username: string;
   password: string;

  public loginForm = this.fb.group({
    password: ["", Validators.required],
    user: ["", Validators.required],

  });

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public fb:FormBuilder, public storage:Storage) {

  }


  doLogin(event){
    this.storage.get('user').then((val) => {
      this.username=val;
      console.log( this.username);
      console.log(val);
  });

  this.storage.get('password').then((val) => {
       this.password=val;
  });
  console.log(this.username); //NOT WORKING
      if( this.username == this.loginForm.get('user').value &&  this.password == this.loginForm.get('password').value)
          {
            console.log("Login Successful");
          }


  }
```

Comment: could you console error in catch function and specify the error message on first log?

Comment: It's not giving me an error. It's just logging undefined when i `console.log(this.username)`

Comment: what is the source of storage I mean native storage or any database?

Comment: Right now storage is native.

Comment: Code looks fine. Please share more/complete function code. It looks like you have done some assignment to this.username variable and have not shared that code.

Comment: Posted the full code but the error is slightly different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Promises are asynchronous..that console log statement is likely called before the db returns val. You can do this operation within `then`

Comment: Is there any way i can retain the values outside `then` ?

Comment: @UjjwalMaheshwari we can use Observable in this case, because we have 2 promises so we have to make sure all of it have to finish before we compare it. Take a look my answer below, the code inside doLogin function.

Answer (score 2):

Promises are asynchronous..that console log statement is likely called before the db returns `val`. You can do this operation within `then`

If you are using promises, you can use `Promise.all`

```
let userCredentials = [this.storage.get('user'),this.storage.get('password')];
Promise.all(userCredentials).then(values =>{
  this.username = values[0];
  this.password = values[1];
   if( this.username == this.loginForm.get('user').value &&  this.password == this.loginForm.get('password').value)
      {
        console.log("Login Successful");
      }
});
```

Promise.all will call the array of promises and wait till all return.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Observable from RxJs to check 2 promises from storage finish.

```
Observable.forkJoin([
   Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('user')), 
   Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('password'))
])
.subscribe(data=> {
    this.username = data[0];
    this.password = data[1];
    if (this.username == this.loginForm.get('user').value &&  this.password ==this.loginForm.get('password').value){
        console.log("Login Successful");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why using observables instead of just `Promise.all([...]).then((results) => {...})`?

Comment: @sebaferreras sure we can do it with Promise, just try to get familar with Observable , thanks .